# Is there a way to record all the incoming and out http requests/responses use apache web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

What I want to do is to view all the requests the media player sent to the Apache web server (streaming video using HTTP), what is happening when you seek/pause the video.

Answer (score 1):

I think `tcpdump` is what you want. On Linux, you can do it with:

```
tcpdump -vv -s0 -i ethx tcp port 80 -w /tmp/streaming.pcap
```

and use `Wireshark` to open the `.pcap` file to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The standard log files will show you most of what you are looking for already.

If "the media player" uses range requests, you can get this logged too by adding directives to your log format (%{Range}, %{Content-Range}).

mod_security can capture a lot more information about the exchanges.